# Create transactional email via install/upgrade script

Tags: magento-enterprise, email-templates, transactional-mail, setup-script

How can I create transactional email templates via an install/upgrade script? I need them populated in Transactional Emails rather than having email templates available in the `app/locale` folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a situation like this it's generally useful to follow the logic of the corresponding admin user action, which posts to `Mage_Adminhtml_System_Email_TemplateController::saveAction()`:

```
$template->setTemplateSubject($request->getParam('template_subject'))
    ->setTemplateCode($request->getParam('template_code'))
    ->setTemplateText($request->getParam('template_text'))
    ->setTemplateStyles($request->getParam('template_styles'))
    ->setModifiedAt(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate())
    ->setOrigTemplateCode($request->getParam('orig_template_code'))
    ->setOrigTemplateVariables($request->getParam('orig_template_variables'));

if (!$template->getId()) {
    $template->setAddedAt(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate());
    $template->setTemplateType(Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::TYPE_HTML);
}

if ($request->getParam('_change_type_flag')) {
    $template->setTemplateType(Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::TYPE_TEXT);
    $template->setTemplateStyles('');
}

$template->save();
```

You can essentially do the same in your setup script, with the obvious difference being that instead of POST params accessed via a request object you are creating your own array directly in the code.

Answer (score 4):

To have a clear answer, here is the installation code I usually use to create a transactional email :

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$code = 'My Mail Title';
$subject = '{{var store.getFrontendName()}}- Mail subject';
$text = 'Content of my mail in HTML format';
$styles = 'Specific style for the mail';

$template = Mage::getModel('adminhtml/email_template');

$template->setTemplateSubject($subject)
        ->setTemplateCode($code)
        ->setTemplateText($text)
        ->setTemplateStyles($styles)
        ->setModifiedAt(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate())
        ->setAddedAt(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate())
        ->setTemplateType(Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::TYPE_HTML);

$template->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```